# Query formula in Google sheets not evaluating the whole column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a Google spreadsheet and in one tab I have a list of employees and managers. In another tab I got some employees. This second list changes based on some different criteria every 3 hours. I sometimes can have 20 persons or sometimes 15.

What I need to do is just add a column right next to the employee with the manager that I get from the other tab, I cannot just add a vlookup on several rows because it will look bad so this is what I'm trying to use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(Sheet1!A:E,"select C where B = '"&$A:A&"' ",1),20,1)
```

But it's not working, only when I use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(Sheet1!A:E,"select C where B = '"&$A2&"' ",1),20,1)
```

`Sheet1` is the one with the employee manager list and the names I need to match come from the current tab from column `A`.

But that obviously only gets one row, so Im not sure what to do.

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to pull the manager's name, from Sheet1, to match against each employee appearing on the list in Sheet2?  So marikamitsos' answer below should do that with a VLOOKUP.  Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the use of the `VLOOKUP` function instead of a query formula.

Please try in your Sheet2 cell `B2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet1!B2:C, 2, 0)))
```

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)